# how change database schema to .dbo in SyncFramework

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

in the sync SyncFramework  after serverProvision.Apply tablename_tracking table and stored procedure created with server connectionstring DB UID for ex: tasnim_DBUser.tabelname_tracking or tasnim_DBUser.tablename_selectchanges ,...

```
server connectionstring : @"Data Source=sitedomain,1433;Persist Security Info=false;Initial Catalog=databasename;UID=tasnim_DBUser;PWD=*******;";
```

I want create with dbo.******

i set  ObjectSchema  but Is not resolved

```
SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn, scopeDesc)
                        {
                            ObjectSchema = "dbo",
                            ObjectPrefix = "dbo"
                        };
```

host is shared , Plesk panel

edit 1 : 
Server Provisioning Code:

```
if (new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn).ScopeExists("MySyncScope2")) return;
DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription("MySyncScope2");
DbSyncTableDescription tableNameTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("tableName", serverConn);
.
.
.
scopeDesc.Tables.Add(tableNameTableDesc);
.
.
.
 try
            {
                SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn, scopeDesc);
                serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
                if (!serverProvision.ScopeExists("MySyncScope2")) serverProvision.Apply();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Clint Provisioning Code:

```
if (new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(db.Con).ScopeExists("MySyncScope2")) return;
   try
            {

                DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDescClint =
                    SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope("MySyncScope2", serverConn);

                SqlSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(db.Con, scopeDescClint);

                if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists("MySyncScope2")) clientProvision.Apply();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: @junet : Please Help

Comment: can you post your provisioning code?

Comment: @JuneT add provisioning code into question

Comment: can you make sure you deprovision first before running the provisioning again. if you have provisioned before and simply added the schema after, that will not apply. also, try setting the schema just before you call Apply()

Comment: @JuneT  i restore db backup not provisioning in host, step 2 provisioning server with top code, i set    serverProvision.ObjectSchema = "dbo"; before Apply() but _tracking table not create in dbo

Comment: @JuneT I think because host is shared not permissions for provisioning. in [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845032(v=sql.100).aspx) show list of Minimum Database Permissions Requirements for Microsoft Sync Framework, how can I see my permissions with query?

Comment: i select user permissions  the result was like dbo user  : Role: db_owner, permissions type: connect, permissions state: grant

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution , db user must have db_owner role and set default schema "dbo" with this query

```
ALTER USER dbUserName WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
```

or in SQL server management studio / security / users / db-username / Right-click / properties /  set default schema "dbo"